# Problem related to inequality for prime counting function

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ prime and define function $f$ as

$$f(n)=\sum_{p-1\mid2n}1$$

**Claim**

Let $\pi(n)$ shows prime counting function

Can it be shown that

$$\pi(n)\sim f(n)$$

And that there exist real number $a$ such that

$$\mid\pi(n)- f(n)\mid<a$$

*I am a beginner in analytic number theory and I'm stuck here with curiosity. Thanks.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then
$$ f(2^n)=\sum_{p-1|2^{n+1}}1 $$
But if $p$ is a prime number such that $p-1$ divides $2^{n+1}$, there exists $k\leqslant n+1$ such that $p=2^k+1$. Since $p$ is a prime number, there exists $\ell$ such that $k=2^{\ell}$ and since $k\leqslant n+1$, we have $\ell\leqslant\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log 2}$. Thus $f(2^n)\leqslant 1+\left\lfloor\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log 2}\right\rfloor$ whereas $\pi(2^n)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{2^n}{n\log 2}$, thus we can't have $f(n)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\pi(n)$, and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}|f(2^n)-\pi(2^n)|=+\infty$ so there doesn't exist a constant $a$ such that $|f(n)-\pi(n)|\leqslant a$ for all $n$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, how $f(2^n)\leqslant 1+\left\lfloor\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log 2}\right\rfloor$

Comment: Let $\mathcal{D}_n$ the set of primes $p$ such that $p-1|2n$, the map $2^{2^{\ell}}+1\mapsto \ell$ from $\mathcal{D}_{2^n}$ to $\left[\!\left[ 0,\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log 2}\right]\!\right]$ is well defined because all $p\in\mathcal{D}_{2^n}$ can be written as $p=2^{2^{\ell}}+1$ in an unique way for some $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$, and it is a one-to-one function. Thus $|\mathcal{D}_{2^n}|\leqslant\left|\left[\!\left[ 0,\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log 2}\right]\!\right]\right|$ that is to say $f(2^n)\leqslant 1+\left\lfloor\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log 2}\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(n)$ behaves more like $\omega(n)$ than $\pi(n)$. For example, $\pi(n)\sim n/\log n$ and in contrast, the number of $1\leq n \leq x $ with $f(n)> (\log \log n )^2$ is $$ \ll \frac{1}{(\log \log x)^2} \sum_{n\leq x } f( n) .$$
This can be proved to be $O(x/\log\log x)$ as follows: the sum is
$$ [x]+\sum_{2< p \leq 1+2x} \#\{n\leq x : n\equiv 1/2 \mod {p} \}\ll x+\sum_{p\leq 3x}x/p\ll x/\log \log x.$$